# Compile error with interfaces and abstract classes

Tags: java

I have an interface and an abstract class:

```
interface MyInterface {int presents();};

public abstract class MyAbstractClass implements MyInterface {
    abstract void presents();
    abstract void chill();
}
```

The compiler complains that in

```
abstract void presents();
```

The return type is incompatible with

```
MyInterface.presents()
```

Offering the following options:

```
make it int type
make MyInterface.presents void type
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Didn't the compiler error say enough?

Comment: abstract void presents(); has a return type of void while the interface's presents() has an int return type... Dude seriously?

Comment: And now he's downvoting all of the correct answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You defined method `presents()` that returns `int` in `Gift` interface.
Then you try to redefine method `presents()` with return type `void` in class named `myClass`.

It is pretty obvious that `int` is not `void`. Thism means that return type is incompatible.

You are confusing with methods inheritance. The problem is that syntax of java (and all c-like languages) does not dictate usage of return value, so even if you method returns `int` you can still call it like following:

`presents();`

So, assume that compiler allows you to have 2 different methods named `presents()`: one that returns `int`, other returns `void`. How can compiler understand which one of the methods to use in our example? The answer is no way. This is the reason that you can override methods using different parameters signature, e.g.

```
presents();
presents(String str);
presents(int n);
```

You cannot however have 2 methods with the same parameters signature and different return type.

Answer (score 4):

In the interface, `presents` is defined as returning an `int`, but in your class that claims to implement the interface, it's `void`. The two need to match.

Answer (score 3):

Because interface having the method `presents()`  and you are trying to change the method signature here.

If you dont want that method  write new one.

```
 abstract void anotherPresents();
```

or

satisfy the original signature

```
   abstract int presents();
```